# NodeJS Closure - Loop Through Array of Objects and Ping a Server with Data from Each Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I have a list of server JSON objects that are read from a JSON file.

I am looping through each server object, taking a value from the object and concatenating it with a string to create a URL. Then I make a get request using the URL to check if the server is up. The result of the get request should set the status of each server object.

The problem is that with each loop the value in the server object is showing as undefined. I can't seem to figure out where the problem with my closure it.

```
var servers = require('./data/servers.json');
var ping = require('http');

var newServers = statusChecker(servers);

function statusChecker(servers) {
var i;
for(i=0;i<servers.length;i++) {
    servers[i]['status'] = function(j) {
        return function () {
                var proto = 'http://'
                var server = servers[i].servername;
                var healthEndPoint = '/health-end-point';
                var url = proto+server+healthEndPoint;
                    //This logs the url with the server part undefined
                    console.log(url);
                    ping.get(url, function(res){
                        console.log(res);
                        return true;
                    }).on('error', function(e){
                        return false;
                    });             
        }()
    }(i);
}
return servers;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status is `undefined` because you are trying to insert asynchronous code `ping.get` inside a synchronous loop.

You wanna take a look about `Promise.all()`, `Promises`, `async/await`

---

Here is an example of the function that's gonna makes the ping

```
 function asynchronousPing(oneServer) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const proto = 'http://'
      const server = oneServer.servername;
      const healthEndPoint = '/health-end-point';
      const url = proto + server + healthEndPoint;

      ping.get(url, function (res) {
        resolve(true);
      }).on('error', function (e) {
        resolve(false);
      });
    });
  }
```

---

Here is how you call it

```
  Promise.all(servers.map(x => asynchronousPing(x)))
     .then((allStatus) => {
        console.log(allStatus);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The error I get when I run this code is UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: Unable to determine the domain name When I hardcode in the servername however, it does return the list of promises- do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Yes you need to add a `.catch()` to the `promise.all` I'm going to edit my answer